# Adding a WHERE clause to a Foreign Key

Tags: sql

I have a table in my database (TableA) that has a column (TableA.Column1) that only allows values from certain rows of another table (TableB.Column2).  This is very similar to a normal foreign key relation except for the fact that only certain rows from TableB.Column2 are allowed.  For example, I may only allow rows from TableB.Column2 where TableB.Column3 > 100;

Is there a way to express this type of referential integrity in a database?  I've tried adding a where clause to a foreign key and I've tried adding a subquery to a Check constraint.  I've not gotten either to work.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer may differ depending on the database system you are using. But an option is certainly to use a trigger.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would this work? Would the trigger be attached to an INSERT or UPDATE and raise an error? I haven't used triggers for ref integrity before and would like to hear details.

Comment: @bzarah It would be attached to both. And I don't really think that you can call this a referential integrity check. It sounds more like a business rule to me.

Comment: Agreed, this really does sound like a business rule rather than simple RI. Though this would probably work, would it not be better to just forgo the trigger altogether, and just enforce in the App tier? 

Also, what would happen if the value in Table A were updated to a value that made the record in Table B invalid? Another trigger?

Comment: @bazrah, yes, that would require another trigger. I agree that it could probably be enforced in the app tier. Depends on the situation. I too often see systems where business experts with no special it knowledge just hack away at the tables through some db management ui.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Klaus.  Both you and bzarah have brought up some interesting cases that lead me to agree that this is more of a biz rule than a ref integrity issue.  We actually enforce this already in our app layer (both in code and in our OR/M mapping files) but i was simply looking for a way to add additional enforcement on a deeper tier.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you only allow "certain" values that are held in a column from Table A, you could create a composite FK in Table B, then add a separate check constraint in your table (Table B)? Though, this sounds like the kind of thing I would enforce in the application tier.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there's any way to do this.

What I typically end up doing in cases like this is create a "dummy" entry (e.g. something like `ID = -1, Text = "state or entry unknown"`) into the table being referenced, and then setting those `TableB.Column2` values to this dummy ID value.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger seems the best answer from a database standpoint...although depending on your setup, this condition might be easier to enforce on the application layer.  What is inserting rows into this table and is it possible to enforce this constraint on whatever is doing the inserting instead of directly on the database itself?  It does carry a few risks doing it in this manner, but it might be simpler depending your setup